# Is there a method to initialise just a part of a vector, then the other one, using numpy.random.randint?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to initialise the first 3 elements of my array (indice), with values between 1 and 120, and the next 3 with values between 1 and 140
Here is what i tried

```
import numpy as np
indice=np.zeros((1,6))
indice[0:3]=np.random.randint(1,121,3)
indice[3:6]=np.random.randint(1,141,3)
```

and I get this error :
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (1,6)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
indices1 = np.random.randint(1,121, (1,3))
indices2 = np.random.randing(1, 141, (1,3))
indices = np.concatenate((indices1, indices2), axis=1)
```